# Adding Application Insights to a WCF service on a locked down IIS box

Tags: wcf, iis-7.5, azure-application-insights

We have a server in our DMZ that we use to host our WCF web services on for some external clients.

This server only accepts connections from a single IP address to make it more secure.

Does anyone know if this it is possible to add application insights to a service that only accepts connections from a single IP? would I need to make changes to allow application insights to work?

Thanks
Martin.

Comment: if you have *outbound* connections enabled, it should be fine.  AI sends telemetry out via https, it doesn't have any inbound connections.

Answer (score 1):

Application Insights collects telemetry and sends it out to back-end servers hosted in Azure. So, till you have outbound connectivity to Azure, your web services will work fine with Application Insights.